# Valid use of ISR_NOBLOCK

Tags: avr, interrupts

I am using two timer interrupts:

- `TIMER0_OVF` triggered every 12 ms, with its ISR only polling a pin, conditionally setting a flag and incrementing a value, so it should complete pretty quick
- `TIMER2_OVF` triggered at a rate of 4 kHz, with its ISR only toggling an output pin to make a piezo speaker beep

Since the TIMER2_OVF interrupts are blocked for a short moment every 12 ms by the TIMER0_OVF ISR, the beep doesn't sound clean, it is overlayed by a "rrr...".

Adding `ISR_NOBLOCK` to the TIMER0_OVF ISR solves this and the beep sounds clean, and the rest still works fine.

However I am unsure if this is a valid use of `ISR_NOBLOCK` and if there is a more elegant way to generate a "clean" beep?

Reading about `ISR_NOBLOCK` in [<avr/interrupt.h>: Interrupts](http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/group__avr__interrupts.html) leaves the impression to me that it is intended for rare cases where nested interrupts are needed and should be used with care.

Comment: The AVR has some dedicated pins (OCR?) that can be toggled from timer events by hardware (without the need to perform the IO operation in the ISR / in code).

Comment: This works nice and makes the ISR and ISR_NOBLOCK unnecessary. Thanks! There is still a click caused by `ADC_SLEEP_MODE` as far as I can tell, but I prefer that over the beep causing noise to the AD conversions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a reasonable use of ISR_NOBLOCK as long as you understand the limitations. If you add more interrupts you may encounter problems.

However, for the beep case, you may be able to get the timer to generate the signal with no CPU intervention. See http://www.wrightflyer.co.uk/Using%20AVR%20Counter.pdf